# C++ Win32 keyboard events

Tags: c++, winapi, event-handling

I am working on my keystroke logger for personal interest and asked a question related to this about yesterday; [While loop using a lot of CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430897/while-loop-taking-alot-of-cpu-usage).

The issue with the program was that it took too much CPU Usage, and people have suggested to make the inputs key-event based.

Since I'm new to the Win32 API, I try to look for references and tutorials that will tell me how to create keyboard inputs as event-based, rather than poll based. But the problems is I could not found any solid examples or references, as it was quite difficult to understand for a complete newbie.

Most of them mentioned that the event-based programming resided in GUI application, yet I want this keystroke logger application to be a console application.

My two main questions from all this is:

- Can I write a event-based console keystroke logger with the Win32 API? If not, what are my options?

and

- Does anyone have any reference websites that will help me understand how to capture keystrokes event-based?

If additional information is needed, I am using Code Blocks under Windows XP with a GCC compiler.

Answer (score 8):

Key logger applications use mechanisms such as [Win32 Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/hooks). Specifically you need to set a `WH_KEYBOARD` hook.

There are move advanced techniques, like creating your own keyboard driver but for a start hooks are a good choice.

**Edit:** To get an idea of how a hook procedure looks like, I post a fragment from my personal utility.

```
// ...
thehook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook_proc, hwnd, 0 );
// ...

/**
 *
 *  wParam, one of the: WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, or WM_SYSKEYUP
    lParam: pointer to a KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure

    (*) "The hook procedure should process a message in less time than the
    data entry specified in the LowLevelHooksTimeout value in the following registry key: 
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop 

    The value is in milliseconds. If the hook procedure does not 
    return during this interval, the system will pass the message to the next hook."

 *
 */
LRESULT CALLBACK
hook_proc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  static long ctrl_cnt = 0;
  static bool mmode = false;
  static DWORD time;

  KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*  kbd = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;

  if (  code < 0
  ||   (kbd->flags & 0x10) // ignore injected events
     ) return CallNextHookEx( thehook, code, wParam, lParam );

  long ret = 1; // by default I swallow the keys
  if (  mmode  ) { // macro mode is ON
    if (  WM_KEYDOWN == wParam  )
      PostMessage(mainwnd, WM_MCR_ACCUM, kbd->vkCode, 0);

    if (  WM_KEYUP == wParam  )
      switch (kbd->vkCode) {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
          mmode = false;
          keys.removeall();
          PostMessage(mainwnd, WM_MCR_HIDE, 0, 0);
          break;

        case VK_RETURN:
          PostMessage(mainwnd, WM_MCR_EXEC, 0, 0);
          break;

        case VK_LCONTROL:
          mmode = false;
          PostMessage(mainwnd, WM_MCR_HIDE, 0, 0);
          PostMessage(mainwnd, WM_MCR_EXEC, 0, 0);
          break;
      }

    /* Which non printable keys allow passing? */
    switch( kbd->vkCode ) {
      case VK_LCONTROL:
      case VK_CAPITAL:
      case VK_LSHIFT:
      case VK_RSHIFT:
        ret = CallNextHookEx( thehook, code, wParam, lParam );
    }
  }
  else { // macro mode is OFF
    /* Ctrl pressed */
    if (  kbd->vkCode == VK_LCONTROL && WM_KEYDOWN == wParam  ) {
      ctrl_cnt = 1;
      time = kbd->time;
    }

    /* Prevent ctrl combinations to activate macro mode */
    if (  kbd->vkCode != VK_LCONTROL  )
      ctrl_cnt = 0;

    /* Ctrl released */
    if (  ctrl_cnt == 1 && WM_KEYUP == wParam  ) {
      if (  kbd->time - time > 40  ) {
        mmode = true;
        PostMessage(mainwnd, WM_MCR_SHOW, 0, 0);
      }
    }

    ret = CallNextHookEx( thehook, code, wParam, lParam ); // let it pass
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: How do you get the HINSTANCE of a different program?

Comment: @MatoušVrba, you don't need to get handles of other programs.

Comment: Link to Win32 Hooks is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

You can do this is a console app as well as a windowed app. You will need to put your keyboard hook in a DLL so that you can capture keystrokes in processes other than your own.

There is some sample code [here](http://developer-resource.blogspot.com/2008/07/setwindowshookex-example.html).

Comment: Just curious, what does a hook exactly do? I've read that it inject itself to another program, or it could be my understand. Also, would this reduce the amount of CPU Usage that the keystroke logger?

Comment: A hook adds a callback to your function when a selected event occurs. You would not need a loop constantly polling the keyboard. You code executes only when necessary.

Comment: See also this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134183/understanding-the-low-level-mouse-and-keyboard-hook-win32/3134570#comment27597902_3134570 (I believe an exe can work for *_LL messages but a dll is required for anything else).

Comment: I submitted an edit to add your comment to your answer. Feel free to reject if you don't like the edit. :)