# Get trigger from console in C++

Tags: c++, c, user-interface

I am writing an application for a robot.

The required UI for the application is described in the pseudo-code below:

```
 while(true){
      if (spacebar is not pressed){
           //do something
      }
      else{
           sleep(1); //wait for a second
      }     
 }
```

If I use cin or some other console input reading function then it will wait for user to press something. How do I ensure that it does not wait to get any input?

I am using Ubuntu. But I do not want it to be OS-specific.

Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217212/how-can-i-detect-if-any-key-is-pressed-by-the-user-in-c-console) seem to be OS specific.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C non-blocking keyboard input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input)

Comment: Unfortunately, either your code will need to be OS specific, or you will need to find a cross-platform library that hides the OS-specifics from you.  C++ does not give you a portable way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

### Terminal Level input

What you are asking for is fairly close to the hardware (key-press / key-release) compared to the "standard input/output" stream concepts. So your implementation would have to be OS specific. Having said that the library to use is curses[1] which has been around for a long time and is standard on a lot of Un*x platforms. The GNU ncurses flavor compiles for pretty much all of them, it is a standard install in almost all Linux environments, and where it isn't installed by default you can find it. It also works well in Windows (cygwin), os/2 and a bunch of embedded systems etc. so you should be able to write a fairly portable software using curses that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what you're asking for.  In the `if`, is the
condition based on whether a space character has been entered,
or whether the user is currently holding down the space bar?  In
the first case, you need something like `curses` (a portable
library which does gets each character as it was entered, 
without echo).  In the second, I don't think that there is
a portable solution.  Even non-portably, you might not be able
to get it if your program is reading from a terminal window
(e.g. xterm); this sort of information is typically only present
as window events, when you created the window in your program.