# How to check when the computer is idle in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, electron, node-webkit, nwjs

I want to run a process in the background in NodeJS, that wait until the computer not in use for 10 minutes. I mean the user do not touch the keyboard or the mouse.

**In other words:** I want to listen to keyboard and mouse events in any window, and notify my app when it is happend.

For this mission, I able to use plain node, or nw.js or electron.

I think that I must to use a C++, native module and DLL's. But I hope there is a better and simple solution.

Do you have?

Comment: so kinda like a keylogger, only not actually recording the keys?

Comment: Good idea to search for. Keylogger+mouse logger

Comment: hmm... dunno how good of an idea it would be to click on anything related to keyloggers

Comment: Find this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33693917/1229624. But searching for easier solution

Comment: I found this API `screen.getCursorScreenPoint()`  in Electron, to monitor mouse movement. Just need now to monitor key press

Comment: wouldn't that only work within an electron window, or while it's active? (dunno, never actually used electron)

Comment: Electron do not must have window. Electron can work in the background

Comment: You could try pings of disconnected or inactive, it would be appropriate.

Comment: @Aminadav: i want the same functionality. did you implement this feature ?

Comment: No. I didn't implement it. If I do it I will use "wmic" to get the CPU usage, and search for peek up and down

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/bithavoc/node-desktop-idle which works on macOS, Windows, Linux, FreeBSD and OpenBSD. I built it for Electron but it works in Node.js in general.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Node module for that: https://github.com/paulcbetts/node-system-idle-time

Answer (score 1):

I reached here somehow googling for the same thing in electron and if you too proceed, this is how I figured it out from [Electron Power monitor API's](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/power-monitor)

```
const {powerMonitor} = require('electron'); 
const idle = powerMonitor.getSystemIdleTime() // it returns in seconds when I am writing this
console.log('Current System Idle Time - ', idle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the user's idle time on OSX using `ioreg` [from this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966890/351505).

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

function idleTime(callback) {
    var command = `ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | awk '/HIDIdleTime/ {print $NF/1000000000; exit}'`;
    child_process.exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        return err ? callback(err) : callback(null, stdout.trim());
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    idleTime(function(err, duration) {
        console.log(`idle for ${Math.round(duration)} seconds`)
    })
}, 1000);
```